# Moving from one ListView Activity to another ListView Activiy

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, nullpointerexception

I am using a `ListView` in Android by creating this class

```
public class HBSListView extends ListActivity;
```

When I click on item in list and I want to go to next `ListActivity` showing relative details of clicked item in previous list.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   

        Intent a = new Intent(iTeam.Ufinder.Application.HBS.HBSDetailView.class.getName()); 
        a.putExtra("store_id", o.get("id")); 
        startActivity(a); 

        // When I use above code it is not working. I want to pass ID also.

        // This works but i do not know how to pass ID this way.
        // startActivity(new Intent("iTeam.Ufinder.Application.HBSDETAILVIEW"));
    }
});
```

`public class HBSDetailView extends ListActivity` this is class in which I want to move.

Mainfest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="iTeam.Ufinder.Application"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Startup"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity android:name=".main"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="iTeam.Ufinder.Application.CLEARSCREEN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="iTeam.Ufinder.Application.MANAGEMENT.Management"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="iTeam.Ufinder.Application.MANAGEMENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="iTeam.Ufinder.Application.HBS.HBSListView"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="iTeam.Ufinder.Application.HBSLISTVIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="iTeam.Ufinder.Application.HBS.HBSDetailView"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="iTeam.Ufinder.Application.HBSDETAILVIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This is the `Exception`:

> 04-15 13:04:43.901: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1417):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{iTeam.Ufinder.Application/iTeam.Ufinder.Application.HBS.HBSDetailView}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: when i run my project by writing this code it generate error and force closed the application.
Intent a = new Intent(iTeam.Ufinder.Application.HBS.HBSDetailView.class.getName()); 
                a.putExtra("store_id", o.get("id")); 
                startActivity(a); 
but when i use this way to go to new listActivity, it works but in that case i can not get the id of clicked list item on the last screen!

i need some methods to go to next list activity with id of selected list item in current list activity.

Comment: Look in the logcat, there must be an exception with stacktrace, if you get force close.

Comment: Ok, i got this exception unable to instantiate activity. and it null point exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you creating Intent like this

```
Intent a = new Intent(iTeam.Ufinder.Application.HBS.HBSDetailView.class.getName());
```

you creating it with action name of your class name. You need to create Intent like that:

```
Intent a = new Intent(HBSListView.this, iTeam.Ufinder.Application.HBS.HBSDetailView.class);
```

The difference is in call signature. First one is of one argument of type `String`. It is stands for creating `Intent` with specified action. Second one is about `Context` and `Class` arguments. It is for creating an `Intent` to call a specified class in specified context.

Also check what `o` is not null.

**EDIT**

Well, if you'd like to start activity this way...

```
Intent a = new Intent("iTeam.Ufinder.Application.HBSDETAILVIEW");
a.putExtra("store_id", o.get("id")); 
startActivity(a);
```

The code above must work as you are expecting....

Comment: The constructor Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<HBSDetailView>) is undefined.

Comment: Oh, i'm wrong... not `this` at the first argument. Use `NameOfYourCurrectActivity.this`

Comment: I am new to android development and i do not have strong knowledge of Intent(); It generate java error if i use the way you are suggesting.

Comment: Still, it throw run time exception that unable to instantiate activity. 
Intent intent = new Intent(HBSListView.this, iTeam.Ufinder.Application.HBS.HBSDetailView.class); 
startActivity(intent);

At this time i am just want to start my new list activity, which if i do this way i am able to start 
startActivity(new Intent("iTeam.Ufinder.Application.HBSDETAILVIEW"));
But this way can i pass ID of selected list item.

Comment: No is doest not work, same exception.

Is it problem of extends Activity/ListActivity? 
Because i am extending ListActivity.
 
public class HBSDetailView extends ListActivity
{
}



It should work :( I need more knowledge !

Comment: Post your exception and stacktrace to your question.

Comment: I posted the exception from logCat.

Comment: Can you show a FULL stacktrace of the error, not just last line? I think the error might be not in `HBSListView` class, but in `HBSDetailView`

Comment: yeah ..... i checked it ........
Intent a = new Intent("iTeam.Ufinder.Application.HBSDETAILVIEW");
          //a.putExtra("store_id", "1"); 
          startActivity(a);

I can go to next page now. Now I will check the problem. 

and I do not know how to send complete stack.

Comment: Now i am able to go to next page by clicking on the list item from the previous list. By using the the code you suggested. and i found problems in HBSDetailView class.

Comment: Well, if everything is fine, you can set my answer as accepted =)

Comment: String store_id =getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("store_id").toString(); i am retrieving the selected store id by this is it correct?

Comment: please can you tell me the way to get the ID on the next class which i passed in previous class?

Comment: No, it is wrong. You should use `getIntent().getExtras().getString("store_id")`. But better to use this code: `getIntent().getStringExtra("store_id")`. It will not fail if no extras is sent via Intent, it will just return `null` and you must check for it.

Comment: how can i communicate further ? My problem is solved, i was facing it because if less development experience in Android. Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
ListAdapter adapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list1));
list.setAdapter(adapter);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long id) {
        HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

        if (position == 0) {
            bundle.putString("store_id", o.get("id"));
            Intent inten = new Intent("Activity name which is you must define in manifest file"); 
            inten.putExtras(bundle);

            startActivity(inten);
        }

        if(position==1) {
            //write your code for when second item of listview clicked
        }

        .....

    }
});
```

Add your `Activity` to the  manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".className"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.test.ACTIVITY" />
        //use this name when you want to run this activty

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I think this is what you want put this in to your listview class